# AlphaAnimations not working properly on Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: java, android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Part of an app I'm working on is using `TextView`s as buttons, and the spec requires that these background-less and border-less buttons provide some manner of feedback to the user when pressed. We decided to adjust the views' alpha values in order to provide the feedback - 40% while pressed, back to 100% otherwise. To facilitate this, I wrote a helper method that slaps an `OnTouchListener` onto the given view to adjust alpha values by using `AlphaAnimation`s with a duration of 0. Here's the method:

```
protected void setButtonFade(View button, final View toFade) {
    button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        private AlphaAnimation pressAnim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.4f);
        private AlphaAnimation releaseAnim = new AlphaAnimation(0.4f, 1.0f);

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (v.isClickable()) {
                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Log.i(TAG, "ACTION_DOWN detected, performing pressAnim");
                        pressAnim.setDuration(0);
                        pressAnim.setFillAfter(true);
                        toFade.startAnimation(pressAnim);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        Log.i(TAG, "ACTION_UP or ACTION_CANCEL (actual value=" + event.getActionMasked() + ") detected, performing releaseAnim");
                        releaseAnim.setDuration(0);
                        releaseAnim.setFillAfter(true);
                        toFade.startAnimation(releaseAnim);
                        break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

For reference, `button` is distinct from `toFade` because in some cases the actual touchable area should be an entire layout, but the view we're fading is only one piece of it.

Now, in most cases this works perfectly. I've tested it on the low and high ends of the API levels we support (Gingerbread and Kitkat, respectively), and it's all well and good. But on Ice Cream Sandwich, this listener only partially works. The `ACTION_DOWN` section behaves as expected, and the view fades when pressed. The `ACTION_UP`/`ACTION_CANCEL` section *fires*, as I determined from the logging statements, but the animation just... doesn't happen. The view remains permanently at 40% opacity until the user navigates away from and then back to the page. I've tested this both on a physical device running 4.0.3 and the BlueStacks emulator running 4.0.4, and on both it reproduces consistently.

So my question is this: Is there a known bug or anything of that sort with `AlphaAnimation`s on ICS? I can't imagine what else could be causing the problem, seeing as how it's getting into the code block that actually runs `toFade.startAnimation(releaseAnim);`. I've done some digging, but most of the answers I've turned up have to do with people setting the `android:alpha` property in the XML, which I'm not doing.

As a side note, I'm currently attempting a workaround to the tune of requiring `toFade` to be a `TextView` and then changing its text color to its old RGB values with an altered alpha. If that works across all Android versions, I'll probably wind up sticking with it, but I still want to know what's going on here, since this is one of the most mysterious bugs I've come across while working on Android.